# How to limit Articles List results by category group

Tags: rest-api, knowledge, articles

I have many Articles. They all belong two one of two Category Groups, which we will call `Old` and `New`.

I can retrieve a paginated list of public knowledge articles like

`/services/data/v44.0/support/knowledgeArticles?pageNumber=1&pageSize=100&channel=Pkb`

But I do not understand how I might limit this Article List to just one category group. (Note - not one *category*, one *category group*)

This is the documentation that got me this far: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_knowledge_support_artlist.htm

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was fairly simple. There seems to be a built-in category of "All", for each Category Group.

So a request like this:

`/services/data/v44.0/support/knowledgeArticles?pageNumber=1&pageSize=100&channel=Pkb&categories={"Old":"All"}`

...returned all articles in the "Old" category group, regardless of what category they were in.

Now to figure out how to only return published articles!